# numpy storing only reference of transposed ndarray

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, transpose

Is it possible to perform the transpose of a ndarray in Numpy without creating a copy of it, much like you flatten array using `numpy.ravel()`?

Comment: Yes: transposing an array with `numpy.transpose()` or `my_array.T` does not make a new copy of the array.

Comment: `transpose` produces a `view`, changing `shape`, `strides` and `order`.  But subsequent operations might have to make a copy.

Comment: My answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657496/python-ravel-vs-transpose-when-used-in-reshape covers this in enough detail that I will mark this as duplicate.